# What is the difference, in internal set property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

i am new to mvc and c#, and i came across these.

This is not a problem as such, just something i've been wondering about.

what is the difference between these two ?

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Title { get; internal set; }
```

and when do you use what ?

removing internal, does not really seem to do anything..

And since i do not know the specific names of these, i haven't been able to find any answers on my searches..

Comment: [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

Comment: thx, had no idea what it was called ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check what is access modifiers: [**internal (C# Reference)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx)

> The internal keyword is an access modifier for types and type members.
>   Internal types or members are accessible only within files in **the same**
>   **assembly**:

Comment: thx, had no idea what it was called ^^

Comment: @andrelange91 you are welcome, mark the answer for correct if helped you.

Comment: sure ^^ just had to wait for it to allow me.